# Как профилировать код по тренировке TensorFlow с помощью tf.Estimator(на TensorBoard)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Я хочу использовать Tensorflow profiler с `tf.Estimator` для профилирования кода и получения результата в TensorBoard. 
Вот несколько способов решения этой проблемы, но они не проходят через TensorBoard:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214251/using-the-tensorflow-profiler-with-tf-estimator.
Вот скриншот желаемого результата:

[image: the wanted result]